# TIdHttp Error 404 Permission denied (Error #10013)

Tags: delphi, http-status-code-404, idhttp

I always use TIdHttp to get data from some pages, but when I try to get the data from the url "https://www.melhorcambio.com/" I get the error (StatusCode = 404 - ReasonPhrase = Permission denied (Error # 10013)), I have already changed some properties like UserAgent, nothing else worked.

the url usually accesses in all the browser that I tested, I also sent a GET by Postman and did not return any errors, but as TIdHttp occurs the error, what can be the correct configuration to make it work?

Exception:

```
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Get('https://www.melhorcambio.com/');
```

Comment: There is no way to tell from this limited information what is actually happening.  You are just going to have to debug the HTTP traffic for yourself. Capture the GET request that a browser generates (most common browsers have a built-in debugger), and capture the GET request that `TIdHTTP` generates (attach an `Intercept` component to `TIdHTTP`, such as `TIdLogFile`), and compare the two for any differences, then adjust `TIdHTTP` accordingly.

Comment: BTW, there is a BIG difference between getting HTTP response code 404 from a webserver, and getting socket error code 10013 from the Winsock API itself. The first is a server-side error, the other is a local OS error. Which are you actually getting?

Comment: Not sure, but it feels to me like this website has been scraped with Delphi+Indy before, and they are blocking you in a dirty way.

Comment: Error 10013 usually means the socket couldn't be opened - things like the local firewall blocked it, or you did something odd like set the from port and it wasn't available.

Comment: @GolezTrol You are 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping Melhorcambio is against their terms of service.  If you override your browser's user agent to present the Indy default string of `Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)` and navigate to the website we see :

> The owner of this website (www.melhorcambio.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature

---

[image]

---

This is most likely specifically targeted at Indy's signature due to prior incidents with scrapers developed in Delphi.  This should be a very strong signal that what you are doing is not welcome.

The method to work around this restriction should be obvious, but recognize that you are attempting to violate the terms of service by doing this... so don't.  Stealing data without authorization is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Except that the OP specification stated: "*I have already changed some properties like UserAgent, nothing else worked*", so it is probably not just the UserAgent alone that alerts the site that scraping is occurring. That doesn't change the fact that postman can get in, though. So that goes back to my suggestion to capture postman's traffic and adjust `TIdHTTP` to mimic it

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's conceivable that they are using other heuristics besides the UserAgent to trap Indy traffic.  It's not really relevant, IMO - OP should not press on with reverse engineering this since it is clearly blackhat activity at that point.  If they want to explore network security strategies the place to do that is in a sandbox, not on a live server with somebody else's valuable data (which they are obviously trying to protect).